# What airfoil type is used on the B727-200F?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, airfoil, boeing-727

What airfoil type is used on the Boeing 727-200F? Is it a NACA profile or something else?

Answer (score 3):

My favourite book for questions like this is [Obert’s Aerodynamic Design of Transport Aircraft](https://www.iospress.nl/book/aerodynamic-design-of-transport-aircraft/). It shows pressure distribution on the 727 wing and gives some AIAA papers as sources. If you track these down, that might reveal more. Unfortunately no airfoil reference is given; however it is very likely that the 727 uses a proprietary Boeing airfoil.

Posting as answer despite not really answering, as it is still more than a comment...